# How to edit TPM-encrypted .vmx?

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, tpm

I am using VMWare Workstation 17 and am running an instance of Windows 11 on it. As per Windows 11 requirements, all the files (including the .vmx) must be TPM encrypted. I am trying to modify the 'bios440.filename' in the .vmx, which can not be done through Workstation 17. I need to edit the encrypted .vmx with a text editor; how can I do that?

Comment: What edit(s) are you trying to make?

Comment: @music2myear I'm trying to change the 'bios440.filename'.

Comment: Add that info the question itself to make the question more clear and complete.

Comment: Maybe [this Python library/tool](https://github.com/RF3/VMwareVMX) could help. I cannot test it, sorry.

Comment: Lol, just found that same project from a quick web search and this VMware forum post https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/Is-there-a-tool-to-allow-editing-of-an-encrypted-VMX-config-file/td-p/1806977

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After help from this community, I discovered the [Python tool](https://github.com/RF3/VMwareVMX) made for en/decrypting .vmx files.